# Print name and count of data with most occurrences in python

Tags: python, group-by, max

I need to print the name of a race course with the most occurrences in a column in a csv file.

I have tried this:

```
popular_course = (race_data.groupby(race_data.Race_Course.tolist(),as_index=False).size())
print(popular_course)
```

and my output is:

```
Aintree        3
Ayr            6
Fairyhouse     3
Punchestown    3
Sandown        3
dtype: int64
```

when I changed the print function to this:

```
print(popular_course.max())
```

I get this:

```
6
```

I need the print function to print the name of the Race Course as well, so that it looks like this:

```
Ayr            6
```

How do I get it to include the name of the Race Course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to go about this. The key is that the popular course is a Series, so you're looking for the max value as well as the corresponding index of that maximum.

Using your existing methodology:

```
race_courses_sized = race_data.groupby('Race_Course').size()
print(race_courses_sized[race_courses_sized == race_courses_sized.max()])
```

Another version

```
pd.DataFrame(race_data['Race_Course'].value_counts()).head(1)
```